# IE8 does not allow to download PDF from remote server but IE9 and Firefox allows

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Code used in MBean:-

```
private StreamedContent           file;
        public void actionGenerate () {

  String reportType= XML/PDF/XLS;
  byte[] reportOut;

  file = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(reportOut), ReportMimeType.valueOf(reportType)
                    .getLabel(), "abcListReport." + reportType.toLowerCase());
}
```

Code in XHTML:-

```
        <div id="p_searchButtons">
            <p:commandButton ajax="false" id="btnGenerateReport"
                target="_blank" value="#{text.common_Submit}"
                actionListener="#{abcListPrintMB.actionGenerate}"
                widgetVar="generateReport">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{abcListPrintMB.file}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </div>
```

primefaces 3.3 is being used.

IE8 able to download the PDF in the local enviroment (local domain)

Answer (score 0):

p:fileDownload doesn't work in IE8 if the download is requested over https. it works only if the IE settings "Do not save encrypted page to disk" is activated.

Check the link below:
https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5934

Answer (score -1):

Security issue with IE 8
You need to check advanced setting of browser

Comment: Can you tell how to do that?